# Confusion with Afrihili Word Machine Problem from NACLO

Tags: grammar, constructed-language, morphemes, african-languages

**The Pretext**
[image]

**The Problem**
[image]

I am referring to the third subproblem

**The Data**

[image]

**The Confusion**

The solution states that it is possible to extrapolate from the data that -*ma*- is used to refer to occupations. Thus, since *iwelemase* contains "ma", it refers to an occupation, and thus we can choose (c). But how do we know it is not simply that "m" and "a" are together by coincidence? For the suffix -*sino*(which is used to refer to groups, like a group of bags), it's unlikely that the letters are together by coincidence because there are so many.

Thanks.

Comment: We need a link to the full set of data, otherwise you only have amadu ~ adu – isabamatu implies isabatu which if you know the source languages is "shoe", but othwise you can't conclude anything from this subset of the data.

Comment: In the data you’ve quoted here, there are four occupations, only two of which contain _-ma-_; the other two (_eshuli_ and _ijamura_) are clearly related to _ishule_ and _ajamuri_, but they are derived in a different way. As @user6726 says, the absence of _sabatu_ means you can’t really conclude anything from _isabamatu_, so you’re left with _adu ~ amadu_, which allows no conclusion – the occupational element may as well be prefixed _am-_ as infixed _-ma-_.

Comment: @user6726, this is the data provided.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The solution states that "Nouns of profession: Infix -ma- is inserted in the penultimate position". I assume that by "nouns of profession" they mean professions where you are not a leader in something, like a principal to a school or a president to republic. Then you would switch the first and last letters.

Comment: If this is all the data they give, I would say that the exercise is fatally defective.